# "The application does not have a valid signature" Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

im trying to test my app on my iPhone but when i click build & run i get this error :C

`App installation failed: The application does not have a valid signature`

anyone here know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Do you have an Apple developer membership? If not, you need one in order to run your app on real device, see here: [Apple Developer Enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

If you do have an Apple developer account, you need to:

- Make sure your app build settings are set properly to use correct
  certificate and provision profile.

[image]

- Make sure your device UDID is registered with your app's provision
  profile in apple member center: [Apple Member Center](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&baseURL=https://developer.apple.com/&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1)